# NetLogo: histogram

Tags: histogram, netlogo

I have a problem with

> [histogram]

In particular, I have a global variable (prova) that records the age of the turtles when they get sick.

In the beginning of the code I define prova as follows

> set prova (list)

Then in the go procedure turtles can get sick, if they do then I want to record their age

> ask turtles [
>        if ... [
>          set prova lput y prova ]]

When I try to plot this variable

> [histogram] prova

I get the following error "expected a constant"

[image]

I don't understand why...since "prova" is a list I thought it worked!

@JenB It should be a list...
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that prova is a list? I can produced a histogram of a list with that code, even if the list is empty. Try printing the list and see what it looks like. If it is a list, can you please show the code where it is created.

Comment: @JenB it should be a list...I modified the question...any ideas?

Comment: @JenB my bad...I just had to delete the square brakets :S ... not  > histogram [prova] but just > histogram prova  i'm so sorry for bothering you...thanks for your support!!!

Comment: of course, should have picked that myself. when i created a test histogram, i automatically did it without [] and didn't even notice them